# Does implementing sorting and paging inside the stored-procedure has disadvantages?

Tags: sorting, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, paging

At my workplace, we can't really decide the best solution to implement paging and sorting. We have two different solutions, and currently use the second one. We do it because it seems like a good idea, but we don't have any real evidence for that.

**First solution:**

The client passes a PageSize, CurrentPage and SortingColumn parameter to the stored-procedure . from the requirements, every output parameter can be sorted. It might look like this:

GetSomething

1. CurrentPage (INTEGER)
2. PageSize (INTEGER)
3. SortingColumn (VARCHAR)
4. SortingDirection (BIT, 0:Ascending, 1:Descending)

**Second Solution:**

The SP doesn't implement any of this, and instead we specify this within the query.

```
SELECT [...]
FROM GetSomething(...)
ORDER BY [ID]
OFFSET 100 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Are both solutions really equally well suited to implement paging and sorting, or does one have benefits over the other? If it helps to know, we operate with a 1TB database which might benefit from small performance optimization that would normally not be taken into consideration.

S.P.: I don't have the required privileges to access the database as DBA, so I cannot simply try it out and benchmark. The actual DBAs for their part don't think this is worth investigating, so I thought I might just ask Stackoverflow in case somehow has hard facts :-)

Answer (score 1):

I usually used the first option. I feel like that little extra control you get to sort the data on client side is worth it. I have yet to see any noticeable difference so you could use either one. In my case I can change the sorting if I need to and don't have to mess with the query.